# How can I insert data from S3 bucket in csv. format into QuickSight?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I have a JSON message that I modified with DataBrew and put it into S3 bucket. This message is in csv format.
I tried to follow the instructions from Amazon at this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-semi-structured-nested-json-data-analysis-with-aws-glue-databrew-and-amazon-quicksight/?fbclid=IwAR2CGY-z-ivrLFNM9dWcQVsPypTpl8wUkgo-5MuRGhsMA-maFnEcX5VQLh4
When creating a Dataset via data source, there is an error that QuickSight cannot connect to the S3 bucket.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJtA5.png)
I am using the JSON manifest file from the instructions which I have modified:
[JSON manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2GMH.png)

Can anyone help me to be able to work with the data further?